# How to store jQuery datatable show entries value store in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How to store Jquery datatable show entries value store in variable

Comment: What you exactly want ? the number of rows per page ? or page count?

Comment: Yes, number of rows per page count

Comment: `var table =  $('#example').DataTable();
var count =  table.page.len();`

Comment: Thanks lot.  Manu Varghese

Comment: Accept my answer in the answer session.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table =  $('#example').DataTable();
var pagelenth = table.page.len();
```

you can find the page length by `table.page.len();`